# Svcutil generates wrong Name property value in DataContractAttribute

Tags: c#, xsd, datacontractserializer, wcf-rest, svcutil.exe

When I use svcutil.exe to generate a Customer class from the definition contained in the xsd file:

```
<xs:schema ...>

<xs:element name="customer" type="Customer" nillable="true" />

<xs:complexType name="Customer">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="id" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="first_name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="last_name" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="phone" type="Phone" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="email" type="Email" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="personal_id" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="address" type="Address" minOccurs="0" />
    <xs:element name="status" type="CustomerStatus" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I get the following definition of the class:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Customer", Namespace="http://www.bluewhite.pl/api/1.0")]
public partial class Customer : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{
```

With the Name property of DataContractAttribute having an invalid value: "Customer" (starting with uppercase letter), since, according to name property of the xs:element, it should be: "customer" (starting with lowercase letter).

I start svcutil.exe as follows:

```
svcutil.exe" *.xsd /t:code /dconly /n:*,Esap.AdtZapisoMessages /o:Messages.cs /tcv:Version35
```

The generated xml must contain a root element named "customer", and I ask you, why svcutil.exe makes this error.

Answer (score 4):

svcutil is entirely correct there; the name of the **type** is `Customer`. From:

```
<xs:complexType name="Customer">
```

The lower-case `customer` is contextual to the usage as a root element, however, that is more an `xsd`/SOAP thing, and does not relate simply to the contract type in isolation. Note that svcutil is interested in contract types; it is a different tool to xsd.exe.

If you want to match a particular xml layout, svcutil is simply the wrong tool; that is a job for xsd.exe. I would expect that xsd.exe would output the required `[XmlRoot("customer")]`.

I tested it, and sure enough:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("customer", Namespace="",
          IsNullable=true)]
public partial class Customer {
```