# DataContractSerializer.ReadObject() fails to create object when used with SvcUtils.exe

Tags: xsd, deserialization, xmlserializer, datacontractserializer, xsd2code

I ran SvcUtil.exe against XSD file to generate class. Then tried to create Object out of XML using following line. I get error shown below. Please see the detailed code below.

```
PersonType prs = (PersonType)xs.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(sFileName)));

Error in line 3 position 58. Expecting element 'PersonType' from namespace 'http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'Person', namespace 'http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/'.
```

Command Used

```
svcutil.exe" "C:\Temp\S1\UseXSDExe\UseXSDExe\Sample2\Prs.xsd" /t:code /language:cs /out:C:\SPrxy.cs /dconly
```

Full code

```
(class generated by SvcUtils.exe)
    [assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/", ClrNamespace="service.a1.com.base1._2005")]
    namespace service.a1.com.base1._2005
    {
        using System.Runtime.Serialization;


        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="PersonType", Namespace="http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/")]
        public partial class PersonType : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
        {
            private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

            private string LastNameField;

            private string FirstNameField;

            public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.extensionDataField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.extensionDataField = value;
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(IsRequired=true, EmitDefaultValue=false)]
            public string LastName
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.LastNameField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.LastNameField = value;
                }
            }

            [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute(EmitDefaultValue=false, Order=1)]
            public string FirstName
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.FirstNameField;
                }
                set
                {
                    this.FirstNameField = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

(code used for converting XML to object)
    public static void convertToObject(string sFileName)
    {
        DataContractSerializer xs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(PersonType));
        PersonType Person = (PersonType)xs.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(sFileName)));

    }
```

(XSD)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/"  xmlns:bse1="http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <xs:complexType  name="PersonType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LastName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="Person" type="bse1:PersonType"/> 
    </xs:schema>
```

(XML)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <pr:Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/ Prs.xsd" 
                xmlns:pr="http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/"> 
        <pr:LastName>   Lane </pr:LastName>
        <pr:FirstName>  Fane </pr:FirstName>
    </pr:Person>
```

I ran XSD.exe on same XSD file. Then I was able to convert XML to Object using `XmlSerializer.Deserialize()`.

XSD does not have any attribute.  I have validated XML against XSD.

Please let me know why `Deserialize()` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XSD specifies a root element name and data type name that are different:

```
 <xs:element name="Person" type="bse1:PersonType"/>
```

When `svcutil.exe` generates data contract classes for this type, it puts the *type name* into the data contract rather than the *root element name*. This appears to be intentional, see [Svcutil generates wrong Name property value in DataContractAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239630/svcutil-generates-wrong-name-property-value-in-datacontractattribute).  Perhaps it does this since the contract type itself could be re-used anywhere in the object graph, and there's no data contract equivalent of [`XmlRoot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that applies *only* when the type in question is the document's root element.

As a workaround, you have a couple options:

1. Hardcode the expected root element name when [constructing the serializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404902(v=vs.110).aspx):

   ```
       var xs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(service.a1.com.base1._2005.PersonType), "Person", "http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/");
   ```
2. Preload the XML into an `XDocument` and use the actual root element name when constructing the serializer:

   ```
       var doc = XDocument.Load(sFileName);
       service.a1.com.base1._2005.PersonType person;
       var xs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(service.a1.com.base1._2005.PersonType), doc.Root.Name.LocalName, "http://service.a1.com/base1/2005/");
       using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
       {
           person = (service.a1.com.base1._2005.PersonType)xs.ReadObject(reader);
       }
   ```
3. Or use `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: I passed root-name in CTOR and that solved the problem. This is a good example for why there is a CTOR that takes Root-name. Thank you verymuch Dbc